# Tab Highlight Color in Spyder

Tags: user-interface, behavior, spyder

Is there a way to color the tab in Spyder?  Brighter colors for the current or active tab would be nice.  Quicker identification of what you are working on.

The default behavior/color of the selected tab is hard to see.  Changing the color to quickly identify which tab you are focused on would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder dev here*) No, unfortunately there is no way to change the color of the currently selected tab (either in the Editor or the Python/IPython consoles).

We are considering to improve this situation in our next major version (i.e. Spyder 3.0).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I looked and could not find anything so this answer was expected.